# Bash: how to store multiple options in a string?

Tags: bash, vim, quoting

Within a bash script, I launch *Vim* with options:

```
vim "-c startinsert" "+normal 2G4|" foo
```

double-quotes are needed, but it could be replaced by simple one:

```
vim '-c startinsert' '+normal 2G4|' foo
```

as those options could vary from one file to another, I want to store them in a string, typically:

```
opt='"-c startinsert" "+normal 2G4|"'
```

and then:

```
vim $opt foo
```

but that does not work, and I tried every combination of quotes, double-quotes, escaping,…

Actually, the only way I find it works is to store only one option per string:

```
o1="-c startinsert"  
o2="+normal 2G4|"  
vim "$o1" "$o2" foo
```

So, is it possible to store two (or more) options in a string? Because when I tried, *bash* seems to interpret them as a file name, for example:

```
opt='"-c startinsert" "+normal 2G4|"'  
vim "$opt" foo
```

*Vim* will open two files:

1. `""-c startinsert" "+normal 2G4|""`
2. `foo`

instead of open `foo` with options `"-c startinsert" "+normal 2G4|"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using arrays, which you can manipulate easily and even use some substitutions when expanding.

Also, note that `-c` is equivalent to beginning a command directly with `+`.

```
opt=(startinsert 'normal 2G4|')
# opt+=('normal l')
vim "${opt[@]/#/+}" foo
```

The last line automatically prepends `+` to each argument.

Answer (score 4):

See [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Use an array

```
opts=(
    -c "startinsert" 
    "+normal 2G4|"
)  
vim "${opts[@]}" foo
```